# Droid App. GUI - mobile website or native?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I have recently been asked to help put together an Android App, mostly UI for myself.
Knowing nothing about it and even less about Java, I stumbled upon Appcelerator.

I got it all installed, and fought my way through getting the Kitchen Sink app to work, but that's not what I am looking for. So I am hoping some here might know or be experienced with this.

First off, is Appcelerator as good as it appears to me at first glance?

Second, my main task here would be that each time someone places a call, I would like to check the number being dialed and, if it falls under specific circumstances, throw up a modal dialog box with options for the user to select.

Is this something doable in Appcelerator or am I fishing in the wrong pond?

Any info/advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First off, is Appcelerator as good as it appears to me at first glance?

[Here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026687/downsides-of-using-appcelerator-titanium-or-equivalent/7027979#7027979) when somebody [asked that yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026687/downsides-of-using-appcelerator-titanium-or-equivalent/7027979).

> Is this something doable in Appcelerator or am I fishing in the wrong pond?

It is not doable in Appcelerator, except perhaps by writing your own Java-based plugin. Even with that I am skeptical -- most of these sort of cross-platform toolkits (e.g., Titanium, PhoneGap) are designed for apps where the UI is point of control, not system-level events like phone calls.

Comment: Wow great response yesterday, helped me quite a bit. And thanks for the info on my question today. It looked like for once I was going to be able to use what I know and not head down yet another path of learning but, as always, it's too good to be true.